# Orientdb cannot insert data inside docker container

Tags: java, api, docker, orientdb, nosql

I am using docker to use orientdb. Using in my localhost i managed to insert data to the database using

```
OServerAdmin serverAdmin = new OServerAdmin("remote:localhost:2424").connect("root","password");
```

However, when i try to do the same thing using docker container i manage to connect create the database but i cannot insert my data

```
OrientGraphFactory factory = new OrientGraphFactory("remote:172.17.0.2:2424/CartoesPagamentos").setupPool(1,10);
OrientGraph graph = factory.getTx();
```

Any ideas about why I can connect and create a database using the API but cannot insert any data?

EDIT :

I ran console.sh and connected to my docker container like this 
    CONNECT remote:172.17.0.2:2424/CartoesPagamentos root password
and i tried to insert a vertex and it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Documentation about how to run the orientDB docker container:

https://hub.docker.com/_/orientdb/

You are running with this command:

`docker run --name cartoesPagamentoTeste -v /orientdb/config -it orient db:latest server.sh`

you're not exposing ports to localhost and it seems you are providing a config folder as volume: as stated on the doc page, if you provide (aka override) a config folder that is empty, orient will start with a very minimal configuration.

So, please, read docs linked above carefully AND read docker docs.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that

> OrientGraph graph = factory.getTx();

works?

Can you access through browser orientDb admin ui by this address 172.17.0.2 ?
Also can you check orientDb docker logs by next command:

> docker logs -f {container name or hash}

Comment: Ok let me see

1 - i am not sure, and it is a good guess haha
2 - yes i can access orientdb admin using this http://172.17.0.2:2480/
3 - ok i am going to check the logs

Comment: But this OrientGraph graph = factory.getTx(); works when i change to localhost, so i guess this is not the issue.

Comment: Inside the docker logs there is nothing new or useful

Comment: If i use orientdb console and connect to my docker container and insert a vertex it also works.

Comment: can you provide your docker or docker compose file?Its becomes more and more interesting

Comment: I am running using this docker run --name cartoesPagamentoTeste -v /orientdb/config -it orient
db:latest server.sh

PS: I am not an expert in docker haha

Comment: Can you provide errors that you have when trying to insert some data from application? And also would be nice to map some volume to your orienDb container, otherwise all data will be lost after restarting container.

Comment: The docker command used doesn't expose ports to localhost. It is impossible to connect to the OrientDB running inside the container pointing to localhost.

Comment: If so how he can access admin site by 172.17.0.2:2480 ?

Comment: As I stated in my answer there are at least two errors: ports are not exposed with -p option, and volume with config is provided( and I guess that volume is empty). The docs I linked shows what's the right way to launch an OrientDB container. In the end, 172... is probably the container's IP.